# How to attach volume to a Docker container executor in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, docker

I am setting up a hadoop testbed that has have two nodes / servers (A, B). Server B contains the docker daemon and other hadoop related services such as Data Node, Secondary name node and Node manager while server A has resource manager and name node. When a container is spawned / launched on Server B using DCE (Docker container executor), I want to attach a volume to it.

Can somebody kindly suggest on how I could do this in the DCE environment?

Answer (score 0):

According to me we can add volume to Docker Container in 2 ways

1) Specify Volume in Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN mkdir /myvol

RUN echo "hello world" > /myvol/greeting

VOLUME /myvol
```

2) Specify the Volume during run time

```
docker run -it v /hdfs/foldername dockerrepositoryyname:version /bin/bash
```

For more details refer https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Hope this Help!!!...

Comment: Thanks for the options 1) and 2). I was aware of the second one but the first option was the one that I was looking for. I read from different posts that it is not possible to specify volume in a Dockerfile. I also wanted to clarify that my question was not on docker containers but on DockerContainerExecutor which is a framework provided by Hadoop to launch docker containers.

Comment: i would suggest read Flocker: https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/ for volume sharing it will be very usefull.